# How to configure code assist, import sentence no wildcard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

In Eclipse code assist, when typing import sentence.

- Operation
  type `import org.`
  type `<Ctrl+Space>`
  popup with suggestions list, `org.apache, ... etc,`.
  select one of suggestion package `org.apache`.
  type `<Enter>`
- Result
  `import org.apache.*;`
- My expectation
  `import org.apache.` and continue popup with suggestions list.

Is it possible to configure My expectation, avoid wildcard imports and continue suggestions ?

[not expectation behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Nj3.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In your eclipse Go to windows>preferences>Java>Code Style>Organize Imports

Check the number written in front of text

```
Number of import needed for .*(org.eclipse.*):
```

In my case it is 99 and I am using Eclipse Oxygen release 2

Comment: Thanks, checked Number of import needed for, 99.